# Would LXC work on Raspberry Pi 2 using Raspbian Jessie or some other latest distro?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie

I'm quite new to the Raspberry Pi world. I'm planning to run LXC containers on my Raspberry Pi 2. Which OS would you guys recommend? should I go for the latest Raspbian Jessie? Would I have to make changes in the kernel to make it run?